# Getting facebook events of a Page with Graph API

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get (only display, not modify) the facebook events of a Page using the graph API.

The URL for that would be: http://graph.facebook.com/nowavezene?fields=events where "nowavezene" is the Page id.

The resulting JSON reads "An access token is required to request this resource".
I even tried the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) but that just gives me

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

My first questions is: **Why?** Why do I need an access token to view events? I can view events even when I'm not signed in to facebook.

**What permissions do I need?**

Neither am I nor the user of the app is the owner of the Page so I can't ask for user_events or create_event permissions.

I would like to do this on iOS if that's relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: You can only get page events through the API if you are the owner of the page.

Comment: Actually, no. One can get events from any Page even if you are not the owner, you just need an access token.
Thanks for @CBroe for guiding me to the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBroe was right in their comment. Reading the manual lead me to the answer, specifically that you need a general **access token**, that will authenticate the request and it will return the events.